# How to fix background image in css file wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

```
#hero {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg') 50% 0 repeat
}
```

Here is my code but still doesn't work

Comment: share the site url

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by fix? Just a normal background image? or fixed background image (paralax effect)?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the
question itself**. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Without more information (some HTML to go with it) or a webpage you are having trouble with, it is very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

I would try something like this, as it sounds like you are trying to have the background image repeat.

```
hero {
background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg') repeat;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this, But you need to add this to your header.php or any PHP file header section. This will not work in CSS file.For more details visit [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852116/css-background-images-in-wordpress)

```
<style>
   .hero {
    background-image: url("<?php echo content_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg") 50% 0 repeat;
  }
</style>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate up a directory or two using `../`

```
hero {
  background: url('../../img/hero-bg.jpg') repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `hero` is your class name thats why prefixed with `.`

In your code I could not find `.` , so check the same one more time.This also can be one issue if it is not there in your code.

Can you try this way:

```
    .hero {
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg');
    background-size: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```