# WordPress page background

Tags: php, wordpress, background

Hi guys I want to set a background for this code and I have no idea what to do
can anyone help me with it? 
thanks

```
/**
 * Template Name: Page Builder Blank
 *
 * The template for the page builder blank.
 *
 * @package Hestia
 * @since Hestia 1.1.24
 * @author Themeisle
 */ ?>

<?php
hestia_no_content_get_header();

do_action( 'hestia_page_builder_blank_before_content' );
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'pagebuilder' );
    endwhile;
endif;

do_action( 'hestia_page_builder_blank_after_content' );

hestia_no_content_get_footer();
```

Comment: Hi @whyidbd 
Welcome to the community,
I think this is a duplicate answer, 
But if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852116/css-background-images-in-wordpress
Then that might help you,
If it doesn't then let us know and we'll help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS background images in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852116/css-background-images-in-wordpress)

Comment: It doesn't help guys I tried them all :(